# What are some functions whose derivatives are negative at every order?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

What functions are there? They have the following characteristics:
(1) Smooth
(2) Every derivative is negative
I know that some exponential functions satisfy such characteristics, are there any other functions?

Comment: Do you explicitly want a function which doesn't use any exponential functions?

Answer (score 3):

A family of examples is given by
$$f(x)=a\log(b-x),$$
on $(-\infty,b)$, where $a>0$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}$. We can compute
$$f'(x)=-\frac{a}{b-x},\;f''(x)=-\frac{a}{(b-x)^2},\;\cdots,\;f^{(n)}(x)=-\frac{a(n-1)!}{(b-x)^n}.$$